# Negative time value in excel

Tags: excel, time, formula

I am using excel to calculate the amount of hours associated to a specific day based on the following criteria in the formula. The following formula works with the exception of when the condition of idle time out is met, and removing the 30 minutes would result in a negative value. In this situation I am met with #VALUE!. In the event of a negative value, I would default to "0" hrs. I could live with the negative value showing as well but I haven't figured out how to reframe the formula to show either result if the condition is met and results in a negative value.

=IF(Q37=O37,M37,IF(K37="idle timeout",TEXT(N37-S37-TIME(0,30,0),"hh:mm")*24,TEXT(N37-S37,"hh:mm")*24))

Comment: How about wrapping in `IFERROR`?

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but you could wrap each TEXT() function in another IF() function.

It might be cleaner to do something like:

`TEXT(MAX(0,N37-S37-TIME(0,30,0)),"hh:mm")*24`